# Copying of "Conditional Formatting" at excel

Tags: excel, copy, conditional-formatting

I want to copy the conditional formatting to another part.
the rule is

> =COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4, "Y")>=2

(if count of "Y" at first top 3 rows is greater than 2)

> then change to "background will be grey"

[Formatting rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwGuh.png)

and apply this to "$B$2:$B$4"

And I want to copy this with that rule to $C$C2:$C$4", $D$D2:$D$D4,,,,

my expectation is that
[expectation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wrMh.png)

However, E column change to "Grey" even if the count of "Y" is 1..
when I tried to copy like this
[how to copy_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVUyz.png)
[how to copy_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8hUL.png)

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understand you correctly, the solution is to make the conditional such that it will copy ok (i.e. with moving relative references). To do that:
a) Enter the condition for the first 'cell group' by selecting `B2:B4` and using the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(B$2:B$4, "Y")>=2
```

b) Then copy `B2:B4` and paste formatting only to other target 'cell groups'

Guiding Principle is: The rules for copying formulas in conditional formats are the same as for copying cell formulas.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
It works! thanks so much

Comment: Glad to help :). Could you now mark this as the answer then? Let's everyone know the question has been answered.

Comment: Done it. Thank you